# Firebase: Trying to return the server timestamp gives a namespace error

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Not sure what I'm doing wrong. The error is pointing to the return type. I'm trying to be careful with adding too many namespaces because I don't want to slow down the cold starts of my functions, but obviously I'm missing something crucial here...

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";
admin.initializeApp();
const fs = admin.firestore();

/**
 * Returns the server timestamp from Firestore.
 *
 * @returns {Timestamp} The server timestamp.
 */
export function getServerTimestamp(): firebase.firestore.Timestamp {
  // return firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp();
  return FirebaseFirestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp();
}
```

Comment: Does my posted answer helpful to you if not acknowledge it so we can dive further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `admin.firestore.Timestamp` or `Timestamp` from

```
import {Timestamp} from "firebase-admin/firestore";
```

to type the return type of your function and to return the Firestore server Timestamp you can use either of the following snippet :

```
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";
admin.initializeApp();
/**
 * Returns the server timestamp from Firestore.
 * @return {Timestamp} The server timestamp.
 */
export function getServerTimestamp(): admin.firestore.Timestamp {
  // return firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp();
  return admin.firestore.Timestamp.now();
}
```

OR

```
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";
import {Timestamp} from "firebase-admin/firestore";  
admin.initializeApp();
/**
 * Returns the server timestamp from Firestore.
 * @return {Timestamp} The server timestamp.
 */
export function getServerTimestamp(): Timestamp {
  // return firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp();
  return admin.firestore.Timestamp.now();
}
```

Reference : [**`Timestamp`**](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/Timestamp.html#.now)